# ResourceContentManager with folders

Tags: xna, c#, xna-content-pipeline

I am attempting to do something like the following:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151031070006/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/06/12/embedding-content-as-resources.aspx)
(Access the content via a DLL)

However, I need to maintain the folder structure of the fonts and images. I have attempted to add the folders to the resources file, but it doesn't add the folder if I drop it in the resources file in VS. I am thinking I might need to embed the content as just a regular folder, and each file will need its property to be set to embedded resource, but I need to use it in another assembly.

I looked at: http://zacharysnow.net/2010/07/03/xna-load-texture2d-from-embedded-resource/
but I think I can only do that with textures. I need to do it with fonts as well.

I looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859699/how-to-add-resources-in-separate-folders and that doesn't seem to help me much.

Whats the best way I can embed my resources in another assembly, while maintaining my content loading strings?

Comment: Hi, I'm the author on the post about embedding textures. My article skips over the content pipeline and as far as I know, SpriteFont does not have a FromStream method. Maybe this article can be of more help to you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/06/12/embedding-content-as-resources.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the `.resx` file and select "View Code". You'll find a tag like the following:

```
<data name="Blah" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
  <value>Resources\Blah.xnb;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
</data>
```

The name that `ResourceContentManager` searches for is the `name` attribute in the `Data` tag. The location that the file comes from (in the `value` tag) doesn't matter. While it does cause the compiler to emit a warning, the easiest way to get the resource to be loaded by the name you want you want is to rename it to "`Folder\Blah`" or similar (note the *back* slash). There is no concept of folders here - it's just a name.

---

I am having a *lot* of difficulty verifying this - but "Embedded Resource" (the build option) seems to be *different* to embedding using a `resx` file. `ResourceContentManager` does not support loading files embedded this way.

*However*, it is pretty simple to create a class like `ResourceContentManager` to load "Embedded Resource" resources. Here's some tested, working code to do exactly that:

```
class EmbeddedResourceContentManager : ContentManager
{
    public EmbeddedResourceContentManager(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        : base(serviceProvider) { }

    protected override Stream OpenStream(string assetName)
    {
        assetName = "YourNamespace." + assetName.Replace('\\', '.') + ".xnb";
        return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(assetName);
    }
}
```

Note the way it converts the supplied path into the path expected by `GetManifestResourceStream`. If you have trouble with getting the path to work - check what the actual paths are with `GetManifestResourceNames`.

Doing it this way will save you having to create and manage a `.resx` file. And it will allow you to use the folder structure as exposed in Visual Studio.